# Why checking null in Array.prototype.forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

In the [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for Array.prototype.forEach()

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
    // |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
    // method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
```

I can't imagine a situation that `this == null` will happen. Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: You need to share the code in the question.. not the image of the code snippet

Comment: The pollyfill attempts to implement the specification step by step. There is no exact equivalent for *ToObject*, which is supposed to throw a TypeError if passed *Null* or *undefined*. The closest thing is calling *Object(this)*, which doesn't behave the same way if passed *Null* or *undefined* so the test is there to throw the right kind of error at step 1 of the algorithm. The step 1 comment should be before the *this == null* test. I think this is wrong anyway, as if *this* is `0` it will fail the test but should not.

Comment: the method is _generic_, so it has to be extra careful about input. ex: `[].map.call("123", Number)`

Comment: also note that all the extra checking make those "official" polyfills very slow compared to say,`_.forEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can pass a custom value for `this` in javascript by using [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call)/[apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply)/[bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) like

```
[].forEach.call(null, function(){})
```